# Security Issues Due To Unknown Surveillance Method

Tags: surveillance, vps

My privacy has been compromised and I suspect some kind of surveillance setup. The stalker can see all outgoing traffic from my digital devices, even when using router in seperate location from my house.

I have antimalwarebytes installed along with payed anti-virus. There was no findings after running a complete analyze with both services.

I have windows firewall set up along with router firewall and WPS2 set on it. Passwords are changed on all services and on router/network.

I am currently using a free vpn on my mobile. I'm considering dowloading a free VPN on my desktop as well to ensure my privacy online. This is only for the sake of protecting my traffic against the surveillance setup by the stalker.

Any ideas what kind of surveillance setup I'm dealing with?

Comment: How have you determined that somebody can see your outgoing traffic?

Comment: With the few details provided, I'm afraid there is not much we can do to answer the question.

Comment: The problem is not that you asked 2 questions, it's that you have not provided any details for us to narrow in what's going on (or if anything is going on). You have basically asked, "I think someone is surveilling me, how are they doing it?" It's simply not an answerable question.

Comment: Oh dear, the scope just too broad.  Spyware, IoT attack (e.g. IP camera) to wikileaks exposed niche method, I add even add more paranoia methodologies if you want.

Comment: The person asking this question is twitter-famous and is probably trying to protect her identity by being vague.  She is very smart in online security and for the purpose of this question you really can assume the "Tech Support Level 1" stuff is all correct.  I would also assume that the stalker is using the intercepted data to torment, harass, or threaten her.  If she had asked this under her "real pen name" it would already have 200 up votes...